# How to launch Android app from link in an e-mail (GMail)

Tags: android

I want to be able to launch the android StubHub application from a link in an email.  You can find an example of this link if you google "Giants Tickets" using a mobile device.  Here is the anchoring code on google's search page that will launch StubHub's app and show a list of SF Giants events.

```
<a class="_Mek" data-packageid="com.stubhub" data-url="intent://stubhub.com/?performer_id=197&amp;GCID=AppLinks:Performer#Intent;scheme=stubhub;package=com.stubhub;S.browser_fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.stubhub.com%2Fsan-francisco-giants-tickets%2Fperformer%2F197%2F;S.android.intent.extra.REFERRER_NAME=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com;launchFlags=0x8080000;end" data-weburl="https://www.stubhub.com/san-francisco-giants-tickets/performer/197/" href="https://www.stubhub.com/san-francisco-giants-tickets/performer/197/" jsaction="bct.cbc" data-ved="0ahUKEwjgid2GmcjVAhVRzWMKHTlaDoQQjjgIXzAA">San Francisco Giants tickets - SF Giants tickets on StubHub!</a>
```

I'm assuming google has additional code on the search page that interacts with the html above.

How would I include a similar link in an e-mail that, when clicked, would launch the android app and take me to the Giants tickets page?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Deep Links to App Content, [Check here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html)

Comment: Wouldn't that require modification of the application's manifest?

Answer (score 1):

Muthukrishnan is right, it looks like Google is using a Stubhub deeplink here. Therefore, Stubhub presumably already has built in support for deeplinks and it just a matter of reverse engineering that Google link. Trying starting by creating a link to something like this:

```
intent://stubhub.com/?performer_id=197
```

I would bet that Stubhub's app already has a manifest line of something like:

```
<intent-filter>
  <data android:scheme="intent" android:host="stubhub.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

And performer_id 197 is probably the ID for the Giants.

Comment: I tried that URL and the browser doesn't respond.  I pulled that original snippit of HTML using a desktop but using dev tools and the toggle device option.I'm wondering if google feeds a different URL to android devices.  Unfortunately I'm not able to run dev tools on my android version of chrome for some reason.

Comment: Ok - this worked: stubhub://?performer_id=197&GCID=AppLinks:Performer

Comment: Thanks for your help!